# Sending data C# to PIC by using USB

Tags: c#, usb, pic

I want to send data, C# to PIC by using USB (UsbLibrary.dll).
I am using below codes for sending data;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] my_buffer = new byte[64];
            my_buffer[1] = (byte)0x01;
            usbHidPort1.SpecifiedDevice.SendData(my_buffer);
        }
```

But I got error as usbHidPort1.SpecifiedDevice value is null (which means that Connected PIC Device is not identified by C#) although vendor and product id coded same in C# and CCS C (PIC). How can send data C# to PIC by using UsbLibrary?

Comment: could you post your entire code?

Comment: should i post CCS C codes?

Comment: data (try to ) sending by using timer as usbHidPort1.SpecifiedDevice.SendData(my_buffer);

Comment: usbHidPort1_OnDeviceArrived and usbHidPort1_OnSpecifiedDeviceArrived are properly fired when you attach the device?

Comment: Yes, they are working properly. And I can get data from PIC to C#. But I could not send data C# to PIC.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that I use to send data to PIC

```
private UsbDevice usb = new UsbDevice();


    if (usb != null && usb.myDevice != null)
                    {
                        byte[] data = new byte[usb.myDevice .nOutputReportLength];

                        data[0] = 0;    // The first byte is the "Report ID" and does not get sent over the USB bus.  Always set = 0.
                        data[1] = b;
                        if (d != null)
                            Array.Copy(d, 0, data, 2, d.Length);

                        this.usb.myDevice .SendData(data);
                    }
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show("Device not found");
```

Comment: I apoligize what is the 'd'?

Comment: I am getting "Device not found" message. Firstly I should solve usbHidPort1.SpecifiedDevice value must not be null. But how?

Comment: What did you write in your Product and Vendor ID in C# and microcontroller compiler? I did write both "1111".

Comment: "d" is the output buffer

Comment: The vendor ID and product ID must be equal to CCS source code